# Упорядочить список по алфавиту в файле Си

Tags: c, алгоритм, gcc, работа-с-текстом

Добрый вечер. Не могу додуматься как можно решить следующую задачу:
Упорядочить список в алфавитном порядке fio ветеранов войны, остальных в списке оставить на своих местах.

Додумался до того чтобы записать ветеранов в отдельный список и сравнивать его с основным, а потом уже делать сортировку. Выгрузил все записи в 2 массива, но не знаю как их лучше сравнить. Может есть способ полегче? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
    int main() {
    char wayListOfVeterans[] = "E:\\Project C\\E6\\Veterans.txt";
    char wayCommonList[] = "E:\\Project C\\E6\\Over.txt";

    char commonList[7][30];
    char listOfVeterans[7][30];
    char sortedList[7][30];


    extractFormFileVeterans(wayListOfVeterans, listOfVeterans);
    extractFormFileVeterans(wayCommonList, commonList);


}

void extractFormFileVeterans(char name[], char mass[7][30]) {
    int i = 0;
    FILE *S1;
    S1 = fopen(name, "r");
    while (!feof(S1)){
        fgets(mass[i], 250, S1);
//        fscanf(S1, "%s", mass[i]);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(S1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не воспользоваться силой функции qsort?

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void*))
```

в данном случае важна функция сравнения 2х значений `compar`

в этой функции тебе можно сделать следующее:

```
int compare(char* str1, char* str2)
{
   если str1 != ветеран, то 
       return -1;
   если str2 != ветеран, то
       return 1;

   const int cmpres = strcmp(str1, str2);

   return (cmpres < 0) ? (-1) : ((cmpres > 0) ? (1) : (0));
}
```

т.е. задай правила как ты хочешь, чтобы вели себя строки.